# IntelliJ - django libraries in virtualenv

Tags: django, intellij-idea

I cant seem to figure out how to have the django libraries resolve in intelliJ. I'm using virtualenv, so the libraries are in venv/lib/python2.7/django . Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Go to `File > Project Structure`, then choose `SDKs` under `Platform Settings` (on the left) and then add your virtualenv in there. After this, select your new Python virtualenv, press OK and you should be good to go.